# Proving the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

I'm given these two sets

$A\subset (0,+\infty ),$ inf$A=0$ and $A$ is not upper bounded

$B=\left \{ \frac{x}{x+1}:x\in A \right \}$

and I have to find the supremum.

Here's the solution my book gives to prove that $supB=1$:

*If $y\in B$ then there is a $x \in A$ s.t. $y=\frac{x}{x+1}<1$*

*We choose $ε>0$ and we have to find $x\in A$ such that $\frac{x}{x+1}<1-ε$ 
that is $x>\frac{1}{ε}-1$* ...

the proof continues but my problem is this segment, how does it go from here $\frac{x}{x+1}<1-ε$ to here $x>\frac{1}{ε}-1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$ \frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{x+1-1}{x+1} = 1- \frac{1}{x+1}, $$
so
$$ \frac{x}{x+1} < 1 - \epsilon \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 1-\frac{1}{x+1} < 1 - \epsilon \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \frac{1}{x+1} > \epsilon, $$
and inverting this gives (this is allowed since $x > 0,$ so $x+1 > 1 > 0)$
$$ x+1 < \frac{1}{\epsilon} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad x < \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1. $$